# How to use thymeleaf without controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use thymeleaf templates in my spring boot application. I've some html pages in the `src/resources/public` directory and I want them to be served wihout writing a controller because I want to write a front end application. I can access the `index.html` file at `http://localhost:8080/index.html` but it's not using the thymeleaf syntax. How can I do it?

I've added the thymeleaf dependency, tried writing a `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` bean but still no luck. Here is what I've done so far:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/public/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to pre-generate the html and then place it on a directory which is accessible by a webserver?

Comment: Yes, something like that. I've a `base.html` and some `child.html`. I want to use thymeleaf to do this and VueJS to do api calls. I don't need spring controllers.

Comment: See this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64775008/spring-boot-cant-resolve-thymeleaf-templates/64780037#64780037